# In AndroidStudio, how do i make the image view adjust its size according to the size of the screen?

Tags: android-studio, android-imageview

I want the image to shrink or increase in size as i change the screen resolution. Please help!

When i changed the screen size the image became either too small or too big for some screen.

Just using some xml tags is it possible to achieve this. PS:NOOB ME

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:-

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Make sure :-

**android:layout_width="match_parent"** ensures the image width matches the container.
**android:layout_height="wrap_content"** lets the image adjust its height based on its aspect ratio.
**android:adjustViewBounds="true"** and **android:scaleType="fitCenter"** further fine-tune scaling while maintaining aspect ratio.